# Vue tables 2 change sort icons

Tags: vue.js, vue-tables-2

I am using vue tables 2 and by default it uses glyphicons. I want to use material icons and I tried to change span to i and to add innerText by javascript but after compiling project it resets back to span with glypicon. I found this: https://github.com/matfish2/vue-tables-2#virtual-dom-functions
But I don't really understand how I am supposed to change it. If there is any other way or better example let me know

Answer (score 5):

In Vue Table 2 There is an option to define the sort icons `sortIcon` [Option Reference](https://github.com/matfish2/vue-tables-2#options)

For example you can add font-awesomne class like this

```
options: {
      sortIcon: {
        base : 'fa',
        is: 'fa-sort',
        up: 'fa-sort-asc',
        down: 'fa-sort-desc'
      }
}
```